# How to set up Firebase Custom definitions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to implement Firebase Analytics in my project. Everything is set up properly, I can see the events in DebugView, but I **can't** see them in Events section.

I read that I should create a Custom Definition in order to see it in the Events..

This is what my code looks like:

```
override fun trackFirebaseScreenEvent(firebaseEvent: FirebaseScreenEvent, customParam: String) {
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString("screen_view", firebaseEvent.screenEvent)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, firebaseEvent.className)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, firebaseEvent.screenName)
        putString("custom_param", customParam)
        }

        firebase.logEvent("My_Screen_Event", bundle)
}
```

So I would like to add a custom event with 4 parameters.

When I go to Custom Definitions, I can create a Custom Definition with only 1 parameter...

I tried to create a "My_Screen_Event" custom definition with "screen_class" parameter, but I can't see the events even after 24h..

Can someone help me or point me to the documentation where this is described in details, as I found all the available resources totally outdated..

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see them in big-query? Click on "your raw events in BigQuery" at bottom of events page. Also make check on Project Settings on firebase console->Integration Tab. Analytics and bigquery is selected for your project